# Zero joint subsums of integers

Tags: number-theory, integers

Fix integers $x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_{10},y_{10}\in [-2,2]$ such that 
$$
\sum x_i=\sum y_i=0\,.
$$

Then, does it necessarily exist a nonempty proper subset $J$ of $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ such that
$$
\sum_{j \in J} x_j=\sum_{j \in J} y_j=0\,?
$$

Comment: Have you investigated the situation with 10 replaced by smaller values?

Comment: For $\{1,\dots,9\}$ this is not true.

Comment: @san Do you have a reference for that? A list of counterexamples? Thanks!

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti but $\sum x_i \neq 0$ in your example

Comment: I can give you a counterexample for $9$: the vector of all $x$ is $(-2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ and the vector of all $y$ is $(2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: I tried very hard finding a counterexample for $\{1,...,10\}$ and I'm quite sure there is none. However, the only proof that occurs to me is by computer, I think it is still small enough.

Comment: Total number of sequences from $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}^{10}$ with sum $0$ is $856945$, so one can easily generate all of them and check all pairs using some nice parallel code.

Comment: @ikbuzsak btw do you have an analytic way to find 
$856945$ or did you use a computer?

Comment: @fonfonx I wrote a short program finding number of sequences of length $5$ and sum $-10, \ldots, 10$, after that all we need to do is calculating $\sum_{i=-10}^{10} (\text{number of sequences with sum } i \cdot \text{number of sequences with sum } -i) $

Comment: It is clear that you can do it by brute force, even if that would not be that nice. (One could ask the same question substituting $10$ with $26$ and the interval $[-2,2]$ with $[-3,3]$.)

Comment: @ikbuzsak You don't have to check all pairs, you can assume that for example the $x_i$ are ordered, so you have to check $55\times 856945$ pairs.

Comment: @Paolo your counterexample can be generalized to $\{1,\dots,(n+1)^2\}$ and the interval $[-n,n]$, so maybe you meant $17$ and $[-3,3]$.

Comment: One can prove by hand that the statement is true for $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the interval $[-1,1]$ computing all cases, but I see no other way than just brute force (though there are some tricks to reduce the calculations).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found thousands of counter examples by using a java code which I'm gonna give at the end (I hope that the code is true because it was just brute force) 
one counter-ex:

### [2, 2, -1, -2, 1, -2, -2, 2, -2, 2]

### [2, 2, -2, -1, -2, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2]

which can be seen easily (I chose this one as easiest)
Because two sequence have 4 common 2's, and for each -1 of second sequence there is -2 in the first sequence with corresponding indices

So, I think you see what I see :)

some other counter examples:

[-2, 2, 0, -1, 0, 2, -2, 0, -1, 2]

### [2, -1, 1, -2, 1, -1, 2, 1, -2, -1]

//////////////

[2, -2, -2, 1, -2, -2, 2, -1, 2, 2]

### [-2, 1, 1, -2, 1, 1, 2, -2, 2, -2]

And here is the code with a lot brute force:

It is a bit messy  but you can arrange the indentation if you want to run the code

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class numbers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>() ;
    Random gen= new Random();
    while (myList.size()<90045){
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        boolean itsdone = false ;
        for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
            arr[i]=gen.nextInt(5)-2;
        }
        while (myList.contains(arr) || (summ(arr)!=0) ){
            for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
                arr[i]=gen.nextInt(5)-2;
            }
        }
        if (!myList.contains(arr) && summ(arr)==0 )
            myList.add(arr);
            System.out.println(myList.size());
    }
    for (int i=0 ; i<myList.size();i++){
        for (int j=i; j<myList.size();j++)
            compareArr(myList.get(i),myList.get(j));
    }
```

}
   `public static int summ(int[] arr) {

```
    int summ=0;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++)
        summ+=arr[i];   
    return summ;`


}
```

public static boolean compareArr(int[] arr1,int[] arr2){
        for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
            if (arr1[i]==0 && arr2[i]==0)
                return true;
            for (int j=i+1; j<10 ; j++){
                if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j])==0)
                return true;
                for (int k=j+1; k<10 ; k++){
                    if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k])==0)
                    return true;
                    for (int t=k+1; t<10 ; t++){
                        if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t])==0)
                        return true;
                        for (int m=t+1; m<10 ; m++){
                            if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]+arr1[m]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t]+arr2[m])==0)
                            return true;
                            for (int n=m+1; n<10 ; n++){
                                if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]+arr1[m]+arr1[n]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t]+arr2[m]+arr2[n])==0)
                                return true;
                                for (int a=n+1; a<10 ; a++){
                                        if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]+arr1[m]+arr1[n]+arr1[a]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t]+arr2[m]+arr2[n]+arr2[a])==0)
                                        return true;
                                        for (int b=a+1; b<10 ; b++){
                                            if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]+arr1[m]+arr1[n]+arr1[a]+arr1[b]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t]+arr2[m]+arr2[n]+arr2[a]+arr2[b])==0)
                                            return true;
                                            for (int c=b+1; c<10 ; c++){
                                                if ((arr1[i]+arr1[j]+arr1[k]+arr1[t]+arr1[m]+arr1[n]+arr1[a]+arr1[b]+arr1[c]==0) && (arr2[i]+arr2[j]+arr2[k]+arr2[t]+arr2[m]+arr2[n]+arr2[a]+arr2[b]+arr2[c])==0)
                                                return true;

```
                }   */
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }   
                }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
        System.out.println("--------------");
        return false;

   } 
}
```

---

*(Added by PL)* Countexamples for $x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_{11},y_{11}$ (see comments below):

[0, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1] [-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2, -1, 2]

[0, 1, -2, -2, 0, 2, -2, -2, 1, 2, 2] [1, -2, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, -1, -2, 2, 2]

[1, -1, -2, -1, -2, 2, -1, 2, 1, -1, 2] [0, 2, -1, 2, -1, -2, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2]

Countexamples for $x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_{12},y_{12}$:

[2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -2, -1, 2, -2, -2, 0, -2] [-1, -1, -1, -1, -2, 2, -2, -1, 2, 2, 1, 2] 
[-2, -1, 2, -2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, 1, 2] [1, -2, 2, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -2, -2, 0, 2]

Countexamples for $x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_{13},y_{13}$:

[-2, -2, 2, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1] [1, 1, 2, 2, -2, 2, -2, -2, -2, 2, -2, 2, -2]

Comment: That was quite unexpected. Could you try it with 11? It is just curiosity, at this point :)

Comment: [0, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2, -1, 2]
--------------
[0, 1, -2, -2, 0, 2, -2, -2, 1, 2, 2]
[1, -2, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, -1, -2, 2, 2]
-------------
[1, -1, -2, -1, -2, 2, -1, 2, 1, -1, 2]
[0, 2, -1, 2, -1, -2, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2]

Comment: These are some of counter-ex

Comment: Merdanov, great. Can you find the largest number you can substitute?

Comment: It's very hard to write for me such a code right now. My code has no tricky algorithm but just brute force .But there are thousands of counte-exs from the cases n=10,11 which makes me feel if there is such a number satisfying this question, it's more than 500

Comment: Nope, I can prove you it is $\le 46$ ;)

Comment: It's interesting.OK, I will try for 20 (if my computer can do that because code involves millions of steps).At least it would restrict boundary. And I would like to learn why $\leq46$ if you can write

Comment: It follows by a result of Steinitz (https://eudml.org/doc/149403) that if $a_1+\cdots+a_k=0$, with $a_i \in \mathbf{Z}^2$ in the centered cube with side $4$, then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that all finite sums $a_{\sigma(1)}+\cdots+a_{\sigma(i)}$ belong to the centered cube with side $3$; from here, you can conclude easily :) Thanks for your tries

Comment: I have compared 60.000 random sequence with sum=0, and there is no match. Most probably answer$\leq20$

Comment: [2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -2, -1, 2, -2, -2, 0, -2]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -2, 2, -2, -1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
--------------
[-2, -1, 2, -2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, 1, 2]
[1, -2, 2, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -2, -2, 0, 2]
-------------- counter-ex for 12 and I have compared 60.000 random sequence with length=13, and there is no match. But also the code hardly found counter-exs for 12 , so maybe there might be 2 or 3 counter-exs for 13. For now, n=13 seems to be the our number

Comment: [-2, -2, 2, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, -2, 2, -2, -2, -2, 2, -2, 2, -2]----------------- unfortunately, it's counter-ex for n=13, I have compared 400.000 random sequences and finally found it.

Comment: Thank you Merdanov, I will add these (counter)examples to your answer above